# Animating with UISwitch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiswitch

I want to be able to create an animation that is started using a UISwitch. I currently have this code to hide some UI elements when the switch is on:

```
-(IBAction)displayStartingAddress:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"starting displayStartingAddress");
    if (enterStartingAddress.hidden==YES) {
        enterStartingAddress.hidden=NO;
        startingAddress.hidden=NO;

    }else{
        enterStartingAddress.hidden=YES;
        startingAddress.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

And I want the switch to cause an animation to the  UI elements to move them down when the "enterStartingAddress" and "startingAddress" is shown.

I am very new to iOS programming and Objective-C so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This question is very unclear can you please rephrase it.

Comment: I did think so. Simply put, I want to move some ui elements when a switch is toggled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the interface elements to hidden right away, no animation will be performed because it will be hidden while it's animating.  What you want to do is to animate the `alpha` property.  That is the visibility of the object. Here is an example of animating the frame and the alpha a bit:

```
-(IBAction)displayStartingAddress:(id)sender{
    CGRect frame1 = enterStartingAddress.frame;
    CGRect frame2 = startingAddress.frame;

    if (enterStartingAddress.alpha==0) { //not the best way to do it to be honest
        frame1.origin.y += 100;
        frame2.origin.y += 100;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{  
             enterStartingAddress.alpha = 1;
             startingAddress = 1;
             enterStartingAddress.frame = frame1;
             startingAddress.frame = frame2;
        }];    
    }

    else{
        frame1.origin.y -= 100;
        frame2.origin.y -= 100;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{  
             enterStartingAddress.alpha = 0;
             startingAddress = 0;
             enterStartingAddress.frame = frame1;
             startingAddress.frame = frame2;
        }]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This honestly isn't failsafe as you might be able to trick the switching into duplicating one of the if statements, thus making your interface objects move down 100 points extra.  But you get the gist.

Comment: @George: Don't forget to mark it as answer (click the green check box) if it helped you!  Then it tells other people that your question is solved.